# Overloaded method overriding: Is there any simplification?

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding

I'm writing overrides of a class, which uses nasty non-C++11 code. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to change the parent class. 
It has two methods with the same name, and one of them is overridden by the child class. Also the the method is passed as parameter to a method. I would like to have functors here, but as I wrote before, I'm unable to change CLassA.
The simplified code looks like this:

Parent class:

```
class CLassA
{
public:
    typedef void  (CLassA::*Method_t)(int x, int y);
    int ForAll(Method_t action, int y);
    virtual void MethodA(int x);
    virtual void MethodA(int x, int y);
};

int CLassA::ForAll(Method_t action, int x)
{
    (this->*action)(x, x);
    return x;
}

void CLassA::MethodA(int x)
{
    printf("CLassA::MethodA: %d\n", x);
    ForAll(&CLassA::MethodA, x);
}

void CLassA::MethodA(int x, int y)
{
    printf("\tCLassA::MethodA: %d %d\n", x, y);
}
```

My first override:

```
class CLassB : public CLassA
{
public:
    void MethodA(int x, int y) override;
};

void CLassB::MethodA(int x, int y)
{
    printf("\tCLassB::MethodA: %d %d\n", x, y);
}
```

My second override:

```
class CLassC : public CLassB
{
public:
    void MethodA(int x) override;
};

void CLassC::MethodA(int x)
{
    printf("CLassC::MethodA: %d\n", x);
    ForAll(&CLassC::CLassA::MethodA, x);
}
```

The calling routine:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CLassA A;
    A.MethodA(1);

    CLassB B;
    B.CLassA::MethodA(2);

    CLassC C;
    C.MethodA(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Output ([link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fa97b873db74523)):

```
CLassA::MethodA: 1
    CLassA::MethodA: 1 1
CLassA::MethodA: 2
    CLassB::MethodA: 2 2
CLassC::MethodA: 3
    CLassB::MethodA: 3 3
```

I definitely don't like, that I have to add namespaces into references and calling (`ForAll(&CLassC::CLassA::MethodA, x);`, `B.CLassA::MethodA(2);`).

Could you please give me a hint, how to avoid these ugly notations?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't believe that the `CLassC::` in `CLassC::CLassA::MethodA` is actually required.  `CLassA` seems to be an unambiguous identifier within `CLassC`.

Comment: Also, it should be mentioned that because `CLassB`'s definition of `MethodA` is non-virtual, if you have a `CLassC` that's being identified currently as a `CLassB` or `CLassA` (such as in a vector of `CLassB` or such), it will call the `CLassB` version of `MethodA` rather than the `CLassC` version.  I'm unsure if this is intended.

Comment: Can you give us a little more detail on what you're actually trying to do?  For instance, if you're calling `B.CLassA::MethodA(2)` will you also be calling `B.MethodA` at all?  If not, why have `CLassB` override `MethodA`, if so why not just create a `MethodB` that calls `CLassA::MethodA` for you?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity `ClassB::MethodA` is implicitly virtual (else the `override` specifier would cause an error), I have added the output that shows it. Btw, with the warning option `-Woverloaded-virtual` GCC gives warnings that some virtual functions are hidden by overrides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're only overriding one of the potential overloaded methods, add a "using BaseClass::MethodA;" to your child classes.

so, ClassB declaration becomes;

```
class ClassB : public ClassA {
 public:
  using ClassA::MethodA;
  virtual void MethodA(int x, int y) override;
};
```

and your definition doesn't change. Then you can do `B.MethodA(2);` without needing to stick the middle ClassA in to disambiguate.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a function in a derived class any overload with the same name in a base class is hidden. This rule applies whether the function is an overload or an override. When having overloaded `virtual` functions, especially elwhen they have an implementation, the normal appeoach is to have `public` and non-`virtual` forwarding functions which call `protected` functions. This way the `virtual` functions can then be overridden individually without affecting the call interface. See for example `std::num_get<...>`.

When you have overloaded `virtual` functions in a base class you can't change the best approach is to make the base class overloads visible with a `using` declaration:

```
class CLassB: public CLassA {
public:
    using CLassA::MethodA;
    void MethodA(int, int) override;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some kind of name clash when you override one of the two method overload with the same name. Renaming the second method to MethodB should fix your `B.ClassA::MethodA(2)`problem:

```
class CLassA
{
public:
    typedef void  (CLassA::*Method_t)(int x, int y);
    int ForAll(Method_t action, int y);
    virtual void MethodA(int x);
    virtual void MethodB(int x, int y);
};
```

For the `ForAll(&CLassC::CLassA::MethodA, x);`, this is just a problème of type inference.
Either you should cast it:

```
void CLassC::MethodA(int x)
{
    printf("CLassC::MethodA: %d\n", x);
    ForAll((Method_t)&CLassC::MethodB, x);
}
```

Or maybe using a `std::function` instead of a raw method pointer should fix this.